# Pass multiple arguments (each argument is a list) from bash script to python script

Tags: python, bash, arguments

I am having a python file that take multiple arguments, each argument is a list. For example, it takes a list of year and a list of month.The `test.py` is below:

```
import sys

def Convert(string):
    li = list(string.split(" "))
    return li


year= Convert(sys.argv[1])
month = Convert(sys.argv[2])

print("There are",len(year),"year(s)")
print("There are",len(month),"month(s)")


for i in range(len(year)):
    print("Working on year",year[i])
    for j in range(len(month)):
        print("Working on month",month[j])
```

Just FYI, I used `Convert()` to convert arguments into lists. For example, with an argument of `"2021 2020"`,`year[1]` will return `2`(instead of `2021`) and `year[2]` will return `0` (instead of `2020`) without being converting into a list first. Not sure this is the most accurate way to do it though.If you know a better way, please comment down below.

Anyway, my main struggle is that in ***command line***, if I run

`python test.py "2021 2020" "9 10"`

It worked fine.And below is the printed message:

`There are 2 year(s). There are 2 month(s). Working on year 2021. Working on month 9. Working on month 10. Working on year 2022. Working on month 9. Working on month 10.`

However, now I have a `test.sh` script that can take the same arguments then pass into python, the bash script just simply won't work.The `test.sh`script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# year month as arguments.
year=$1
month=$2

echo 'Working on year' $year 
echo 'Working on month' $month

python path/test.py $year $month
```

Then in ***command line***, I ran this

`sh test.sh "2021 2022" "9 10"`

Python seems to believe `"2021 2022" "9 10"` is 4 arguments instead of 2 even though I quote them separately.
Here is the message it prints:

`There are 1 year(s). There are 1 month(s). Working on year 2021. Working on month 2022.`

How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happened"? Does it not even print "Working on year"?

Comment: That sounds like something completely different is going on. The `echo` is not conditional, so you might be running a different script, a bogus interpreter (On a related note, [`sh` is not `bash`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Scripts)!), or something else weird.

Comment: `year` contains a space-separated string which, when *unquoted*, expands to two distinct words after word-splitting. Your Python command was `python path/test.py 2021 2022 9 10`, not `python path/test.py "2021 2022" "9 10"`.

Comment: @chepner sorry not sure I followed. When I run `python test.py` I did quote the arguments. So python knows its 2 arguments. However when I run `sh test.sh` python seems to believe `"2021 2022" "9 10"` are 4 arguments instead of 2.

Comment: @l0b0 you were right. I edited my question.

Comment: `test.sh` does *not* quote the arguments. The quotes in the assignment are not part of the value, and even if they were, they would be treated as literal characters in the expansion, rather than quoting the expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You should add double quote to prevent globing and word splitting, check this link for more details: [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086)
Change test.sh to:

```js
#!/bin/bash

# year month as arguments.
year=$1
month=$2

echo 'Working on year' "$year"
echo 'Working on month' "$month"

python path_to_test.py/test.py "$year" "$month"
```

Comment: I tried. Then the message becomes `Working on $year` instead of 2021 or something

Comment: @tuangou share with me the result

Comment: @tuangou Did you use `'$year'` or `"$year"`?

Answer (score 0):

you could use `$@` to refer to all command-line arguments

```
# year month as arguments.
year=$1
month=$2

echo 'Working on year' $year 
echo 'Working on month' $month

python path/test.py $@
```

Comment: I tried. This didn't make a change.